# Prisma 2 delete mutation is returning null

Tags: graphql, mutation, prisma2

I am using ApolloServer/Prisma2/GraphQL/Typescript/MySQL
I have created two models, User, and Post. My createUser and createPost mutations are working fine. However, I am having trouble getting my delete mutations working. Focusing on the deletePost, here is what I have in my code.

<<schema.graphql>>

```
type Query {
    posts: [Post!]!
    users: [User!]!
  }

type Mutation {
    createPost(title: String!, body: String!): Post!
    createUser(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!): User!
    deletePost(postId: ID!): Post
    deleteAllPosts: [Post!]!
 }

type Post {
    id: ID! 
    title: String!
    body: String!
    author: User
    published: Boolean!
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String! 
    posts: [Post!]!
}
```

<<schema.prisma>>

```
model Post {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
  title         String
  body          String
  published     Boolean  @default(false)
  postedBy      User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId      Int?
}
  

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  posts     Post[]
}
```

<<Mutation.ts>>

```
async function deletePost(parent, { postId }, context, info) {
    return await context.prisma.post.delete(
        {
            where {
                id: parseInt(postId)
            }
        },
            info
     )
}
```

Note that the createPost and createUser are also in the Mutation.ts file and are working correctly. So I'm assuming there is no issue with the Apollo server.

When I use the GraphQL playground I use the following:

```
mutation {
  deletePost(postId: "1") {
    id
  }
}
```

with the following result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "deletePost": null
  }
}
```

I want the mutation to return the deleted post (at least the id if nothing else). In addition, the database is not deleting anything. I'd appreciate any help.